# Ground Jump Cable attached to White on GFCI Receptacle?

Tags: gfci

Just bought a home, and going through minor electrical issues.
The guest bathroom GFCI wasn't working. According to the prev. owner's labels in the fuse box, there is a single 20A breaker that services ONLY that receptacle, and it's tripped, and will not reset.

So, I pulled off the wallplate and see that the ground is connected, but there is also a jumper connecting the ground screw to the white neutral... HUH???

[image]

My first instinct was just to wire it up correctly... but I wanted to check to see if this was actually indicating a larger issue before I go messing around.

Maybe this was a temporary solution for something that they never got back to?

Maybe the breaker is bad, and this (I guess?) would just make sure any wayward electricity goes to ground until the breaker could be replaced?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

The ground being tied to the neutral is a code violation and should be removed. If the GFCI has power and will not reset after that it has failed and needs to be replaced. They are designed to fail in a safe or off position.

Comment: Amen to comments by Ed and Jack.  But I have to wonder WHY would anyone do this?  Clearly there's a ground wire there. One other comment: "Is the outlet fed by a GFCI breaker (IE, does it have a TEST button on it)? If so, connecting the neutral and ground would certainly confuse it. Heck even the local GFCI outlet would be confused. This is silly.

Comment: To move forward, I'd disconnect all 3 wires, cap them individually with wire nuts to be safe and try to reset the breaker in the panel. If it still won't reset, you have worse problems. I've dealt with rodent damage to wires that lead to tripped breakers and they weren't even GFCI or AFCI. The breaker was doing it's job and the cable had a true short  cause by rodents (mice) damage.  And like Jack suggested, pull the cover off the main panel and inspect for other issues.

Comment: @george Anderson all 3 ok but I would just pull the hot if verification of the breaker thinking the GFCI receptacle was bad , wirenuts on any loose current carrying conductors are a good idea. For others yes this means the neutral if the branch circuit is live the neutral can be a shock hazard.

Comment: Thanks, I capped the wires, and the breaker still wouldn't reset. The breaker is pretty old, but there's probably something wrong with the wiring in the walls >_<

Comment: Dura next remove the wire from the breaker itself. If the breaker still won’t reset it is bad, if it resets then the problem is between the panel and that GFCI receptacle.

Answer (score 3):

This is a no no and you should remove that jumper. Some DIYer wired that before checking this site. You might want to check inside the main panel to see if you can find any more weird stuff.